# Next/Previous Element in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Im attempting to figure out how to traverse through an arraylist.. Cant seem to get it down.

When the next button is clicked, the next record is loaded into the GUI. However, I dont know how to split the arraylist data if "listIterator" is used. (Same for previous button)

I dont need to use the iterator, I'm not entirely sure on a method that would allow for previous/next aside from it though.

```
public void next(){
ListIterator<String> listIterator = records.listIterator();
  if(listIterator.hasNext()){

    String [] info = listIterator.next().split(",");
      jtfName.setText(info[0]); //textfield
      jtfNumber.setText(info[1]);
      jtfCost.setText(info[2]);
      jtfOwed.setText(info[3]);

  }

  else {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No more records to display");
  }
```

}

Comment: Sorry, but - what is the question here?

Comment: Can't you just store an index and increment/decrement it?

Comment: Yes, I believe I can. This makes the issue 10x easier. I was over complicating it. Thank you!